# Conditional with BackgroundImage property fails

Tags: .net, vb.net

I get rhis error:

```
Operator '=' is not defined for type 'Bitmap' and type 'Bitmap'.
```

On this code:

```
Private Sub Button_Toggle_ClickButtonArea(Sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button_Toggle.ClickButtonArea
    Sender.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Enable
    If Sender.backgroundimage = My.Resources.Enable Then... ' ERROR
End Sub
```

How to do what I need?

How to evaluate the Bitmap Image with my resource PNG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to the below.

```
Private Sub Button_Toggle_ClickButtonArea(Sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button_Toggle.ClickButtonArea
  If cObj(Sender.backgroundimage).Equals(CObj(My.Resources.Enable)) Then Set_Service_Status("Themes", Service.StopIt, True)
End Sub
```

The reason for this is as follows.
The comparision is to be made between two OBJECTS so we convert them to objects using CObj(itemname)

And then once we have the converted objects we use EQUALS to compare one to the other

```
If CObj(This).Equals(CObj(That)) Then Something
```

Comment: Is not working for me, maybe because the control object is a BMP image (I figure), and my resource is a PNG?. PS: I don't want to confuse you, My control backgroundimage is the same resource which I'm trying to evaluate, they are "equals", but I think when I set the property it is automatically converted to bmp first.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it has something to with the my.resource.enable being in a resource and not as an image.

Comment: Nope, it is added as an Image :/

Comment: Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.fromresource.aspx for further info, What i'm thinking is that your comparing a bitmap (sender.background) to a pointer to a resource image (my.resource.enable)

Comment: What are you saying is I need STRICTLY declare the bmp for example like this"Dim bmp = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Enable)" and then try to do the comparision? I've solved doing that but I will know if I need to load the Image from the resource first, without exceptions.